# why my search bar is not working in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

created a simple search in the Django blog but it's not working. why search bar is not working in a blog web app ? its nothing to search in the search bar when searching something in the search box.

**- urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

**- views.py**

```
def search(request):
query = request.GET['query']
allPosts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
params = {'allPosts': allPosts}
return render(request,'home/search.html', params)
```

**- search.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Search Results {% endblock title %}

{% block blogactive %}active{% endblock blogactive %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container my-3">
            <h2>Search Results</h2>
            {% for post in allposts %}
            <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row my-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                    <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">Article by {{post.author}}</strong>
                    <h3 class="mb-0">{{post.title}}</h3>
                    <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{post.datetime}}</div>
                    <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{post.content | truncatechars:500}}</p>
                    <div class='my-2'>
                    <a href="/blog/{{post.slug}}" role='button' class="btn btn-primary">Continue reading</a>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">

                </div>
            </div>

            
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. In template you are using `allposts`(all lower case) where you are passing `allPosts` from context, ie: `params = {'allPosts': allPosts}`. So you need to change either one of them, like change in context:

```
params = {'allposts': allPosts}
```

And one improvement suggestion, replace `href="/blog/{{post.slug}}"` in the template with `href="{% url 'url_name' %}"`. More information can be found in [url tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: thanks now it's working I will replace href in templates.